# How to add new node in QSGNode

Tags: qt, qml

I have a `QQuickItem` which display text cursors for a text editor, at first I has just a cursor (`QSGGeometry`), placed in `QOpacityNode`. When I increase the number of cursor, new cursor get placed in opacity node, but the call to `QSGNode.appendChildNode()` genereates ***segmentation fault***.

```
QSGNode * CursorsArea::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *, QQuickItem::UpdatePaintNodeData *){

if (node == nullptr) {
    node = new QSGOpacityNode;
}

if (!alpha.update()) {
    if (alpha.currentAlpha >= 1.0) {
        alpha.setCurrentAlpha(0.0);
    }
    else {
        alpha.setCurrentAlpha(1.0);
    }
}

if (editor == nullptr) {
    return node;
}

if (node->childCount() != editor->selectionsCount()) {

    if (node->childCount() < editor->selectionsCount()) {
        for (int i = node->childCount(); i < editor->selectionsCount();
             i++) {
            auto * geometryNode = new QSGGeometryNode;
            auto * geometry =
              new QSGGeometry{QSGGeometry::defaultAttributes_Point2D(), 2};

            geometry->setLineWidth(m_cursorW);
            geometry->setDrawingMode(QSGGeometry::DrawLines);
            geometryNode->setGeometry(geometry);
            geometryNode->setFlag(QSGNode::OwnsGeometry);
            node->appendChildNode(geometryNode); // Segmentation fault here
        }
    }
    else {
        while (editor->selectionsCount() < node->childCount()) {
            node->removeChildNode(node->firstChild());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Stack trace:

> 1  QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::nodeWasAdded(QSGNode *,
>   QSGBatchRenderer::Node *)                         0x7ffff1248245      2 
>   QSGBatchRenderer::Renderer::nodeChanged(QSGNode *,
>   QFlags)                    0x7ffff124b592     3 
>   QSGRootNode::notifyNodeChange(QSGNode *,
>   QFlags)
>   0x7ffff1235b18    4  QSGNode::markDirty(QFlags)
>   0x7ffff1235b99    5  icL::editor::CursorsArea::updatePaintNode
>   cursorsarea.cpp 91 0x7fffd1124939     6 
>   QQuickWindowPrivate::updateDirtyNode(QQuickItem *)
>   0x7ffff12d7320    7  QQuickWindowPrivate::updateDirtyNodes()
>   0x7ffff12d7794    8  QQuickWindowPrivate::syncSceneGraph()
>   0x7ffff12d8cc7    9  ??
>   0x7ffff12665b3    10 QQuickWindow::event(QEvent *)
>   0x7ffff12e3b06    11 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject *,
>   QEvent *)                                               0x7ffff7ac0e14
>     12 QApplication::notify(QObject *, QEvent *)
>   0x7ffff7ac86e1    13 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject *,
>   QEvent *)
>   0x7ffff020ec39    14 QWindowPrivate::deliverUpdateRequest()
>   0x7ffff0c65853    15 QWindow::event(QEvent *)
>   0x7ffff0c65d8b    16 QQuickWindow::event(QEvent *)
>   0x7ffff12e3a5c    17 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject *,
>   QEvent *)                                               0x7ffff7ac0e14
>     18 QApplication::notify(QObject *, QEvent *)
>   0x7ffff7ac86e1    19 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject *,
>   QEvent *)
>   0x7ffff020ec39    20 QTimerInfoList::activateTimers()
>   0x7ffff026139a    21 ??
>   0x7ffff0261c5a    22 g_main_context_dispatch
>   0x7fffef92d3cf    23 ??
>   0x7fffef92ef89    24 g_main_context_iteration
>   0x7fffef92efce    25
>   QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags)
>   0x7ffff0261fc9    26 ??
>   0x7fffe1e18e12    27
>   QEventLoop::exec(QFlags)
>   0x7ffff020d8cc    28 QCoreApplication::exec()
>   0x7ffff0215bc6    29 main
>   main.cpp

How I can fix it?

Comment: What line of the code produces the error?

Comment: node->appendChildNode(geometryNode); // Segmentation fault here

Comment: Do you call to `QSGNode::markDirty`? Have you tried to check it with debugger and make sure all objects exist? Where did you set a data for the line? It would be nice if you can create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so one of us could run and test it

Comment: the minimal example: https://gitlab.com/lixcode/qml-append-sg-node-crash

Comment: To add new cursors (veritcal lines) just click on window in any place.

Comment: I have solved the problem in minimal, complete and verifiable example. For solution see the commit https://gitlab.com/lixcode/qml-append-sg-node-crash/commit/bc6814abaea5463f7590ab33462b6229cf5c5a3e